# How do I accept that math is hard?

Tags: education

Ever since I began studying mathematics, there were times where I really enjoyed doing so, and then there were times where I didn't enjoy it at all and simply wanted to quit. I guess everyone knows these kind of feelings while studying mathematics, it's fairly common.

When I end up not enjoying mathematics at all again, this situation generally follows as a result from not understanding or solving something fast enough. (at least from my perspective) Whenever I start telling myself such stories, I try to compensate for my inability of not being good enough as I expect from myself.

I begin to talk myself into believing some kind of genius-myth, like: "There must be a way to do this better than anyone else within a much shorter amount of time, and all I have to do is finding the right way."

Of course there is no such thing as the "right way". I am not a genius and I never will be, but in times like these, I have trouble accepting this as a matter of fact, which makes the whole situation even more unpleasent. For the most part, my fellow students don't care much for mathematics at all. (there are very few students that aim for a normal bachelor-degree anyway, most of them are going to be teachers) Therefore, there is nearly no one to communicate with about these struggles.

Do you recognize yourself somehow? Do you also sometimes feel the urge to compensate for your inabilities with such nonsense? How do I accept the fact that math is simply hard and that I have to work for it to get the results I wish for?

Comment: There are high and low points in any career path. Those who make it past the low are the ones who make it in the end. Whether or not one of those people are you is completely your decision.

Comment: I could have written these words when young. During studies, there are hard times but some other are so pleasant ! Keep going on ! You will do it ! I even know that you will do it. Cheers.

Comment: When you look at the work of people like Paud Erdös, Srinivasa Ramanujan or more modestly (!) Andrew Wiles, you understand that mathematical skills follows a logarithmic scale. You are somewhere on this scale, so what ?

Comment: But how do I deal with those kind of feelings? Should I just try to expect less from myself?

Comment: Be welcoming the obstacles. They are what makes life interesting.

Comment: Life is hard. First come to terms with that.

Comment: The best remedy I've found is to remind myself to spend less time thinking about myself, my approach to the problem, and whether or not I'm "good enough," and instead spend more time thinking about something actually interesting: mathematics! If I fail to solve a problem, or if somebody else gives a better solution, I try to remember the bright side: I have probably learned some cool trick or nifty idea in the process. Ultimately, completely getting over it probably involves some combination of "getting used to being stuck" and "learning when to move on/ask for help," which just takes time.

Comment: I'd like to share the advice that my professor told to me when I first started taking studying at the graduate level. He told me that in mathematics, things are often presented as being well-understood, and systematically explained. This is what we see in textbooks, and in all our lower level courses, so I think many people come to expect that problems are all systematic in the same way. This just isn't true. In his experience, he thinks about problems sometimes for months or years before getting anywhere. Sometimes he even forgets about problems, and doesn't remember them..... (1/3)

Comment: ...... until a long time in the future, when he stumbles upon some little idea that allows him to make progress. His advice to me was that if at any time in my mathematical career I feel stuck, like all is lost and I can't do anything at all, to take some time, and remember back to a few months ago, to all the amazing things that I *could* do, and to take some solace in the fact that everyone gets stuck. Try to keep my head up, and to remember that if I got this far, I can keep going. And most importantly, if anyone, anywhere has figured out how an idea works......(2/3)

Comment: ......... then you can figure out how that idea works too. It only takes one person. Head up! You can do it!

Comment: "Why should I continue doing maths when it is hard?" Well, you have to do *something*, and *everything* is hard, so the best you can do is to choose something you enjoy at least a little bit and keep on going...

Answer (score 9):

Keep running. Things may change with struggle .

Comment: But it's so hard to keep running when you don't see a sense in doing so.

Comment: No one claimed that it will be easy.  Don't be a weenie and keep on running, Forest!  Some day you'll earn what you seeded today. Honestly. Most of us have been there before.

Answer (score 5):

**Mathematics is too broad to declare enjoyable or not.**

Maybe I love reading J.K. Rowling but I don't enjoy Dostoevsky.  My point here is that like many subjects, "Mathematics" is too broad of a subject to either find generally enjoyable or not.  In fact, I bet I would really love reading Dostoevsky if I actually understood him more...

I think it comes down to the fact that nobody enjoys being confused.  Whether a problem you're working on is difficult or not usually correlates with the enjoyment IF you at least understand the problem.  I feel that this is actually what puts people off of math when they are young: not having a good teacher who can get the student to understand what they are doing so that later on math just seems like a nonsense endeavor.

Some mathematics is incredibly difficult.  I'm seeing two questions:

1. How do I accept math can be difficult
2. How do I accept I have difficulty with math

For the first, you just accept it!  For the second, you should focus on the math and not yourself.  Take enjoyment in what you can do.

Answer (score 3):

I was pretty good in maths during my school life especially Euclidean Geometry  & Calculus.
I participated & cleared many Maths Olympiads/Competitions like RMO (USAMO of India) & I understand what you are trying to say.

Since I solved all the problems alone I would often spiral down the thought chain that there are some super-human mathematicians who would surely have gotten a better & elegant solution than mine & in only fraction of the time that I took.
When I was unable to solve a problem I thought I am very foolish that I can't even solve this simple problem which would have been pretty easy to solve for a guy good in Maths.

The way I overcame this is by observing very smart people solve a problem & thinking with them as they reached a solution.

So I think you should find very smart people & try to study with them & solve problems with them & the genius-myth you mentioned would surely vanish.

Comment: I am currently pursuing Mathematics Hons (2nd semester) and I can relate to these thoughts. I am even considering to quit my studies altogether and to do something else. The fact, that I am nothing, but a stupid human being, trying in vain to grasp the beauty of mathematics, is troubling me every moment. There are some god-gifted, as well as extremely hardworking guys, to whom these concepts and problems are merely child's play. I don't think I am ever going to recover from this dark, empty void, but I am trying to. :)

Comment: Glad to hear that you found it relatable.
TBH- I didn't pursue my Maths career and took up CS instead BUT my theoretical maths knowledge has been instrumental in helping me become the best in the field of Blockchain/Decentralisation etc.

Checkout my youtube channel : https://www.youtube.com/arnavvohra7